# WPF control for tokenizing

Tags: wpf, tags, controls, tokenize

I didn't found any wpf library that contains control for tokenizing (tagging) text input. Perhaps I can't find the library, because I incorrectly call this component. How it is called or where there is such a library?

[image]

Comment: This is too big to post, but the walkthrough here seems to do just what you're after: http://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

The DevExpress WPF library contains several data editing controls that provide the option to work in token mode, which is your required functionality. Here is the overview page for this: https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/17861/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Editors/Editor-Types/Token-Editors

Note: This is a paid product. They offer a free trial if you would like to try out their ecosystem.

Another option is to create your own. This can be done fairly quickly (with minimum functionality, but probably enough fro your needs) using a RichTextBox and custom InlineUIContainers. There is a blog post here that fleshes out the idea and provides a sample implementation: https://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens